# Keras Layer unknown, try to load a model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, keras-layer

I saved a trained model with this code but cannot load it because the layer isn't in keras.layer, here's my code, thanks in advance for your precious help !

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals

import numpy as np

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

train_data, validation_data, test_data = tfds.load(
    name="imdb_reviews", 
    split=[
   tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[:60]),
   tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(tfds.percent[60:]),
   'test'
],
    as_supervised=True)

train_examples_batch, train_labels_batch = next(iter(train_data.batch(10)))

# to use for more accuracy... : google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim128/1
embedding = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(embedding, input_shape=[], 
                           dtype=tf.string, trainable=True)
hub_layer(train_examples_batch[:3])

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model.fit(train_data.shuffle(10000).batch(512),
                    epochs=20,
                    validation_data=validation_data.batch(512),
                    verbose=1)

results = model.evaluate(test_data.batch(512), verbose=1)

for name, value in zip(model.metrics_names, results):
  print("%s: %.3f" % (name, value))

# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("my_model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("w_model.h5")
```

when I try to load it I obtained a problem cause it doesn't recognize the layer "hub_layer" created with a tensorflow dataset. Hope you know how to deal with it.

Comment: Can you parse the tracelog?

Comment: You can use custom_objects, refer to this github post: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4871#issuecomment-269714512

Answer (score 2):

the problem here is that model save file does not contain code of that layer. you can solve this problem using custom_objects and pass dictionary to this argument.

The trick here is to copy the unrecognized name, put it to string in dictionary as key and provide that layer as its value

**For example**

```
import tensorflow_hub as hub
layer_dict = {
    "hub_layer":hub.KerasLayer
}

model = model_from_json('model_file',custom_objects=layer_dict)
```